# Opentok hello world activity unable to join session

Tags: android, session, opentok

I am trying to run opentok helloworld application
 using this [opentalk_hello_world](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-demo) (please login on git to access that url).

I did everything as it was instructed in that url which I mentioned above but I was not able to run the app.

There are two queries:

1. on 4th point its said that "The first time the app runs, it prompts the user to allow the app to use the camera to stream live video." which i was never asked!
2. on 5th point its said that "Once the app connects to the OpenTok session, it publishes an audio-video stream, which is displayed onscreen. Then, the same audio-video stream shows up as a subscribed stream (along with any other streams currently in the session)."

I have created sessionid and tokenid and replaced them in the activity. When I run the app I get the following in the logcat

```
02-25 14:07:00.640: E/demo-hello-world(6421): session failed! com.opentok.android.OpentokException: Session Compatibility Mismatch - There was a mismatch with the session's capabilities. You're likely trying to connect Android to a P2P Flash session on the web.
```

can you guys let me know where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

did you create your session id from your dashboard? When generating the session id, make sure that p2p is not enabled! Also, make sure your token has publisher role so you can stream video. [image]